# Regarding the calling mechanism of jquery function

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have created one jQuery function to check if elements exist or not like:

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function () { 
    return this.length > 0; 
}
```

Then I call:

```
if ($("#MyDiv").exists() == false)
   alert('not exist');
else
   alert('exist');
```

If I call jQuery function above it works. But can't we call the jquery function like this way `exists('#MyDiv')` ? If I try to call this way then I am not getting result...why?

Comment: Unless you have defined a function `exists`, you cannot call it (obviously?). Of course you can easily define one which accepts a selector and performs the same operation as you defined in `$.fn.exists`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @FelixKling. What all of we're missing, what this function is good for...

Comment: @gdoron: I agree with you that such a method is rather unnecessary in this particular case, but the question still stands (imo) apart from what the method is doing.

Comment: @Thomas, Are you interested in the `exist` function only, or are you asking a more broad question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below,

```
$.exists = function (selector) {
    return $(selector).length > 0;
}
```

and use as,

```
$.exists('#test')
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/skram/hgaPt/1/

Please use this in a bigger picture, using it for simple thing as exist is just a overkill.

Comment: why u did not specify jquery function prototype like jQuery.fn.exists = function () {) rather u wrote code like $.exists = function (selector) {)....both are same? jQuery.fn keyword is optional. please discuss

Answer (score 2):

ARRG, please, don't use this useless `exist` function!

It can be simply with:

```
if ($('#MyDiv').length)
    // Exist
else
    // Doesn't exist.
```

No plugins needed, everyone knows what this code does, **Don't use `exist`**.

Comment: I don't think that's point of the question.  I assumed `exist` was just an example.

Comment: @Rocket. I don't think so, look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31044/601179) see how many people like that useless function.

Comment: "Syntactic sugar causes cancer of the semicolon." -Alan Perlis

Comment: @Rocket. Actually the main problem with a lot of the jQuery programmers, they have **ZERO** knowledge in javascript, so they didn't thought about `if($(...).length)` instead of `$(...).length > 0`

Comment: @gdoron: There is nothing wrong with being explicit (`> 0`). This can make the code easier to understand. But I guess this is rather a matter of style.  `if($(...))` is worse ;)

Comment: @FelixKling, I expect every programmer ever touching\reading my real code to know about truthy-falsy nature of javascript values, so `> 0` is just noise. IMO.

Answer (score 0):

```
exists('#MyDiv')
```

This won't work because you didn't make a function called `exists`.  You made a function called `jQuery.fn.exists` (`jQuery.fn` is the `prototype` of jQuery objects).

For `exists('#MyDiv')` to work, you need to make a function called `exists`.

```
function exists(sel){
    return $(sel).length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.fn` is equal to `$.prototype`, so indirectly using `$.fn` you are hooking your functions to jQuery object prototype, so the selector needs to be passed to the jQuery object not the chained function name.